# ModalPopupExtender does not postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have this page where in i have a ModalPopupExtender. Now the panel that shows up as a ModalPopup has 2 buttons namely "Invite" and "Cancel". My problem is that when i click on either of the buttons postback does not occur and i am unable to run my server side code.

When i click on the "Invite" button it simply hides the ModalPopupExtender control and does nothing!!

```
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeInviteFriend" runat="server"
  TargetControlID="lbInvite" PopupControlID="pnlInviteFriend"
  OkControlID="btnInvite" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
  BackgroundCssClass="diabledBackground" Y="100"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>

 <asp:Panel ID="pnlInviteFriend" runat="server">
  <div class="popUpBoxBackground" style="height:230px; width: 400px">
   <div class="popUpBox">
    <div class="popUpHeader">
     <b>Invite a Friend</b>
    </div>
    <div class="popUpBody" style="height:210px">
     <div style="padding: 10px">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
       <tr>
        <td>You have chosen to invite your friend to join this community.</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px">Email address of your friend:</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="padding: 4px 0px 5px 0px" align="right">
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
          TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="inputTextbox"
          Width="99%" Height="28px"></asp:TextBox>
         <span class="smallInfoText" style="color: #000">In case you want to invite more than 1 friend, separate their mail id with a ;</span>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px">Would you like to add a personal note?</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="padding: 4px 0px 5px 0px" align="right">
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtInvitationText" runat="server" 
          TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="inputTextbox"
          Width="99%"></asp:TextBox>
         <span class="smallInfoText" style="color: #000">If not then leave it blank and we will take care of the note : )</span>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="right">
         <asp:Button ID="btnInvite" runat="server" OnClick="btnInvite_Click" Text="Invite" style="margin-right: 10px" Width="60px" />
         <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" Text="Cancel" Width="60px" />
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </asp:Panel>
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out this part of your markup:

```
OkControlID="btnInvite" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
```

Update after comment:

In the initialization phase, client side, this piece of code gets executed:

```
    if (this._OkControlID) {
        this._okHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this._onOk);
        $addHandler($get(this._OkControlID), 'click', this._okHandler);
    }
```

So basically it creates a handler towards the _onOK function:

```
_onOk: function(e) {
    /// <summary>
    /// Handler for the modal dialog's OK button click
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e" type="Sys.UI.DomEvent">
    /// Event info
    /// </param>

    var element = $get(this._OkControlID);
    if (element && !element.disabled) {
        if (this.hide() && this._OnOkScript) {
            window.setTimeout(this._OnOkScript, 0);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
},
```

as you can see it calls e.preventDefault(); which causes the normal behavior of the OKControl to not go through while this.hide() will close the modal popup itself.

I suggest you read the **ModalPopupBehavior**.debug.js from the control toolkit if you want to know more.

Comment: thanks buddy, that worked out just the way i wanted it to...but could you explain me the phenomena in detail....
what actually happened when i removed that code ??

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign the ok control, so event will work fine.

Also it works for cancel control just don't assign them.